# Python: Listen For Change In Variable (float)

Tags: python, listener, actionlistener

I have written a simple script to monitor one of an RC airplane's servos though a ground station, and when the output value of that servo goes over a certain amount, it writes the aircraft's current gps coordinates and bearing to a file. I have opened the file as "a" mode, to append it instead of overwriting the previous things. I consider myself fairly decent at Java, but just started Python for this script, so I'm sort of lost.

Is there a way I can efficiently listen for a change in this value (a float) and only perform the file writing when it gets to a certain value? The usual value is 900, an I want to print to the file when it gets to 1900. So far I have been using a "while True" loop to keep checking this, but IMO that's a pretty bad practice. From what I've read the only way to do this is through Java's actionListener.

```
import time

count = 1

while True:
    if cs.ch6out > 1100:
        object = open("C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\ScriptOut.txt", "a")
        object.write("Target: " + str(count) + "\n")
        object.write("Latitude: " + str(cs.lat) + "\n")
        object.write("Longitude: " + str(cs.lng) + "\n")
        object.write("Bearing: " + str(cs.nav_bearing) + "\n")
        object.write("\n\n")
        object.close()
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1000)
```

Comment: Are you allowed to modify cs' class definition? You could make `ch6out` a [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), and make the getter perform logging when it exceeds your target value.

Comment: Where is `cs.ch6out` coming from? Nothing in the code you posted indicates that it can change inside the `while` loop.

Comment: cs.ch6out is coming from a class within a program called MissionPlanner. It is updated periodically (every 2 seconds in this case). I cannot change this class, but when I run this script from MissionPlanner is has access to the cs class (cs = Current State). Website for more info: http://copter.ardupilot.com/wiki/common-using-python-scripts-in-mission-planner/